# static_assert placement problem

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Having (don't worry about length of this code, concentrate on struct X and Range)(you can copy and paste and should compile):
**EDITED**

```
    #include <limits.h>
#include <type_traits>
//This is from file "Static_limits.h"
template<class T>struct static_numeric_limits;
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<signed char>
{
    enum {min = SCHAR_MIN,max = SCHAR_MAX};
};
/*This "surplus" template is here for the reason that char is threated diferently from signed char */
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<char>
{
    enum {min = SCHAR_MIN,max = SCHAR_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<unsigned char>
{
    enum {min = 0x0,max = UCHAR_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<unsigned short>
{
    enum {min = 0x0,max = USHRT_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<signed short>
{
    enum {min = SHRT_MIN,max = SHRT_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<unsigned int>
{
    enum {min = 0x0,max = UINT_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<signed int>
{
    enum {min = INT_MIN,max = INT_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<unsigned long>
{
    enum {min = 0x0,max = ULONG_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<signed long>
{
    enum {min = LONG_MIN,max = LONG_MAX};
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<unsigned long long>
{
    static const long long min = 0x0;
    static const long long max = ULLONG_MAX;
};
template<>struct static_numeric_limits<signed long long>
{
#define LLONG_MAX     9223372036854775807LL
    /* maximum signed long long int value */
    static const long long min = LLONG_MIN;
    static const long long max = LLONG_MAX;
};
//This is from main.cpp
typedef unsigned long long uint_64;
typedef signed long long int_64;
/*Validates range*/
template<class IntType, uint_64 value_,bool C = std::is_signed<IntType>::value>
struct validate_range;
template<class IntType,uint_64 value_>
struct validate_range<IntType,value_,true>
{
    enum {value = (static_cast<int_64>(value_) >= static_numeric_limits<IntType>::min) &&
                  (static_cast<int_64>(value_) <= static_numeric_limits<IntType>::max)
         };
};
template<class IntType,uint_64 value_>
struct validate_range<IntType,value_,false>
{
    enum {value = (value_ >= static_numeric_limits<IntType>::min) &&
                  (value_ <= static_numeric_limits<IntType>::max)
         };
};
template<class IntType, IntType value>
struct Range
{
private:
    const IntType value_;
protected:
    const IntType getRange()const
    {
        return value_;
}        public:
    Range():value_(value)
    {
        /*eb*/
    }
    //this static assert in here won't work even though this class is a base class for Low
    static_assert((validate_range<IntType, value>::value),"Value constant is out of range");
};
template<class IntType, IntType value>
struct Low : private Range<IntType,value>//HERE Range IS INHERITED BY Low
{
    const IntType getLowRange()const
    {
        return Range<IntType,value>::getRange();
    }
};
template<typename IntType, uint_64 low_range>
struct X : public Low<IntType,low_range>
{};
    //static_assert((validate_range<IntType, Value>::value),"Value constant is out of range");//this static doesn't work if placed in Low's base class namely Range        };
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        X<unsigned char, -2> x4;//this should fail
        return 0;
    }
```

So basically what I'm asking here is why static_assert((validate_range::value),... doesn't work if placed in Range struct which is in turn a base class for Low which is in turn base class for X but works if placed directly in struct X
**EDITED**
Guys I'm very sorry for the previous code. I've edited my post and this time it should work (exposing the real problem). Once again, sorry for last code, I just don't know what've happened.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work," what happens?

Comment: You'll at least need a `#include <climits>` on the top to get this to compile. I still wasn't able to get it to compile on g++ (with `-std=c++0x`). `std::is_signed<T>` should be `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed`, and `low_range` is referenced but not defined anywhere.

Comment: There's a couple of typos (probably? or else missing code, like what is `low_range`) and it would probably help if you state what you want to achieve in plain english.

Answer (score 1):

rHere are the errors I get.  They seem fairly self explanatory:

```
test.cpp:115:45: error: use of undeclared identifier 'Value'; did you mean 'value'?
     static_assert((validate_range<IntType, Value>::value),"Value constant is out of range");
                                            ^~~~~
                                            value
test.cpp:99:37: note: 'value' declared here
    template<class IntType, IntType value>
                                    ^
test.cpp:127:39: error: use of undeclared identifier 'low_range'
        struct X : public Low<IntType,low_range>
                                      ^
test.cpp:128:9: error: expected class name
        {
        ^
3 errors generated.
```

**Edit**

Your latest post compiles for me (except for a warning about redefining LLONG_MAX).

Comment: Wow, impressive error messages - "did you mean 'value'?". :-) Clang I guess.

Comment: You're correct: clang.  That team has put emphasis on quality error messages and it **really** shows! :-)